Obsidian Push to GitHub Fails After User Password Change (SSH Key Update)
I changed my computer user password today, and after that, I tried to use my Obsidian notes. However, when I attempted to push my Obsidian files to GitHub, I encountered an error:
Here is the full error message:
fatal: key not valid for use in specified state
bash: line 1: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory

I tried setting the origin URL with my username and password, but that didn't help.
